# Auto Enable/Disable for QML Controls 2.3 Button with Icon

Tags: qt, button, icons, qml, qt5

Using Qt 5.10, Qt Quick2 2.10, Qt Quick Controls 2.3 Button class, I have defined a button that displays an icon and a button that displays text as follows:

```
Button {
    iconSource: "my_button.png"
    enabled: sometimes
}

Button {
    text: "My Button"
    enabled: sometimes
}
```

I would like the icon button to behave just like the text button below it for user interaction. It should change its appearance appropriately when it is in the click, hover, or disabled state.

Hover and click mode are working, since they only rely on changing the icon background, and not the icon image itself.

Disabled mode is not working. The button displaying text behaves correctly (the text and the border turn gray), but in my icon button, nothing changes when it is disabled.

Details about my icon file:
The RGB values are all black (#000000) corresponding to the color I want my icon drawing to be. The image shape is drawn in the alpha channel. I have tried playing around with the other channels, but I have not had success.

Here is an image from my project. You can see a row of icon buttons on top, and three text buttons below. Although some of the icon buttons are disabled, they all look the same.

[image: My icons above - the icon all the way to the left is disabled, but looks just like the others; three text only buttons below, one of them disabled]

Comment: You could explain yourself better and maybe put some images to understand you.

Comment: Hi eyllanesc - have you used QML? This is all default behavior.

Comment: I use QML, but I do not understand your question, which is what you want to get.

Comment: Cleaned up the question, and posted a solution. Qt Quick 2.3 does not yet have a page documenting the Button class, so I think this question may be helpful for some.

Comment: Weird, this question is getting so many down votes, I may delete it. It seems to me it addresses a gap in the QML documentation. I'll leave it for a few more days.

Answer (score 1):

I have cleaned up this question. Maybe should not have posted a question the day after St. Patrick's Day :)

The Qt docs for the Button class instruct you to set the iconSource property to define the url for the icon image file. However, this is for QtQuick 1.4.

QtQuick 2.3 does not appear to have documentation yet, though it is the standard for the current Qt 5.10.

The Button (Controls.2/Button.qml) inheritance list is:

```
QQuickItem
  QQuickControl
    Templates.2/QQuickAbstractButton
      Templates.2/QQuickButton
        Button or {Style}/Button
```

There is no longer any iconSource property in Button. Instead, you access the icon property of QQuickAbstractButton, which is of type QQuickIcon. Using icons in Qt Quick 2 is documented here -  [Icons in Qt Quick Controls 2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-icons.html#using-icons) -, along with.. a Button example!

Since the parent classes of Button use prototype inheritance, it seems that the properties of the parents, such as "icon" are available in the Button class as well. You can look in the qml directories in the Qt installation directory to see the class declarations without downloading the whole Qt source code.

So, my new Button code looks like this:

```
Button {
    icon.source: "my_button.qml"
    icon.color: enabled ? "#000000" : "888888"
    enabled: sometimes
}
```

Note: I am using the Fusion style, but this does not affect the existence of the icon property, which is inherited from a prototype.